# Why must Regex escapes be escaped?

Tags: java, regex

Getting down and dirty with the regex implementation in Java, I spent a good two hours today troubleshooting a regex that was supposed to match consecutive whitespaces, but didn't. After googling and swearing, I found out that it was because i had to do `String args[] = line.split("\\s+");`.

What is the reason for the double backslash in java, as opposed to the `split(/\s+/)` that I'm used to from perl?

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I need this to make sense to me, and at the moment it doesn't.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2733264/548225

Comment: First it has to translate the characters you wrote into a java string.  and then it translates that java string into a regex.  That's two levels of escape sequences